# Charging works well with new USB cables only

Tags: charging

When trying to charge my android devices (Arc S and Nexus 7 (2013)), I noticed that when using new USB-cables, the charging process is going quite fast, but after some weeks (usually four-five) the charging process rapidly slows down, and some weeks later the devices don't charge anymore, i.e. resulting in the need of new cables. Is that a hardware failure, or why do I have to replace the cables every second to third month?

Comment: Have you checked the USB contacts for wear and tear? Both in your phone(s) and the cable(s).

Comment: The USB contacts in the phone can definitely be old, due to 5 years extensive usage. But why do the cables work at the beginning, and fail later?

Comment: Have you considered changing cables as suggested in my solution?

Comment: Changing cables works for some months, then I have to change again...

Comment: I understand that. Is that the case with thick cables also as mentioned in my answer below, is what needs to be checked

Comment: Maybe new cables permit more current flow when they are new than when they are 2 months old, and the stronger current can compensate for the heightened resistance of the worn contacts. This is just speculation, though.

Comment: @TamoghnaChowdhury. Your point is valid in two ways 1. Cable resistance will not deteriorate so fast unless it is a poor make (supporting my answer) , 2. Contacts are also adding to resistance probably being old but that will be constant not change with time

Comment: cutting open the insulation reveals silver coloured conductors, then it can be the case that they’re made from tinned copper conductors (which are easier to solder) but otherwise are substantially the same for conductivity as for copper. Otherwise, they could be cheap aluminium, which is a worse conductor (68% higher resistivity) and is more mechanically brittle-from comments of post quoted in my answer

Comment: Length: Typical ~50 cm, no markings (at least not visible). No extension board used. Cables have to be changed every five to six months.

Comment: Thanks. Can you please edit your question, it says " weeks" there.  You just mentioned months. Also adding how many times you already changed in the question, may help someone else guess the reason?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hardware is not "capable" to decide charging rate based on "newness" or otherwise of cables

In all probability, USB cables you are using are of poor quality, wrong length and thickness

What I would suggest:

1. Google for "24 awg micro USB cables **Less than or equal 2 meter length** and purchase from reputed vendor

**Why these specs for USB cable?** Long explanation but needed to emphasize choosing the right USB cable

- Current carrying capacity depends on resistance, for the same Voltage.

  > Ohm's Law  Current = Voltage divided by Resistance

Resistance in turn depends on thickness

> Resistance = Length divided by Area (ignoring resistivity)

Resistance is inversely proportional to the area of the wire

Less area = Thinner Wire = More Resistance = Less Current (you cannot make out thickness of the conductor by looking at it- they all seem to be equally thick but internally the conductor thickness varies)

Similarly, reducing length of wire decreases resistance

Arc S has [800 mA](http://vi.raptor.ebaydesc.com/ws/eBayISAPI.dll?ViewItemDescV4&item=201118746869&category=123417&pm=1&ds=0&t=1453388444102) and Nexus 7 has [1150 mA](https://sites.google.com/a/mst.edu/robert_ruark/projects/google-nexus-7-charging) Charging current rating and the cable should support that

**Cable Length ,thickness, current rating required for device** both matter when choosing the right cable. [USB Cable Resistance: Why your phone/tablet might be charging slow](http://goughlui.com/2014/10/01/usb-cable-resistance-why-your-phonetablet-might-be-charging-slow) relevant to your device specs says

> For smartphones, with a requirement closer to 1A, 24AWG wires up to 2m could be sufficient, or 1m at 26AWG, and 50cm at 28AWG.

**Nexus 7 is more choosy:** It will **stop** charging if voltage levels drop and resistance comes into play again. [Google Nexus 7 Charging](https://sites.google.com/a/mst.edu/robert_ruark/projects/google-nexus-7-charging) goes into details and says

> Nexus 7 will stop charging if the input voltage is less than the internal battery voltage plus 0.2 volts.

2. Use an app like [Ampere](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.gombosdev.ampere) or [3C Toolbox](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ccc71.at.free) to measure the charging current (somewhere midway of your regular charging time is a good time to measure, as the values may be different just when you plugged in or towards end of charging)
3. Calculate the charging time required using the [Battery Charge Time Calculator](http://www.csgnetwork.com/batterychgcalc.html) ( choose efficiency of charging at 90 %)

Repeating this test say once a month for a few months at least would give an indication if it is a hardware issue (weird as it sounds). If there isn't a significant change, it only confirms that poor USB cables being culprit

---

**For everyone:** [USB Cable Resistance: Why your phone/tablet might be charging slow](http://goughlui.com/2014/10/01/usb-cable-resistance-why-your-phonetablet-might-be-charging-slow) is a useful read to understand why it is a good idea to spend more but **buy the right USB cable**

Comment: It's hard to imagine how a mechanical fault in the cable could cause the charging to get gradually slower, but I admit I don't have a better hypothesis.

Comment: @DanHulme :  edited the answer with supporting sources. Point is that these cheap USB cables with use and abuse develop more resistance, ascend this goes worse with time. This is the only explanation that I can think of that fits the situation described by OP